# Find the minimum value of $P=\frac{1}{2-x}+\frac{1}{2-y}+\frac{1}{2-z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers such that $x^3+y^3+z^3=3$. Find the minimum value of 
$$P=\frac{1}{2-x}+\frac{1}{2-y}+\frac{1}{2-z}.$$

I think that we need to show that $\dfrac{1}{2-x} \ge f(x)$, where $0<x<\sqrt[3]{3}$ but I still have no solution.

I really appreciate if some one can help me. Thanks!

Comment: hint: Lagrange mulitplier surely works.

Comment: Can you post it?

Answer (score 3):

I make a sketch of the work here by Lagrange Multiplier. I am sure there are other more "elegant" techniques from exotic inequalities like AM-GM, Schur, CS, etc...I would be more than happy to see a proof of such work.Meanwhile, we can take this path... We are led to:
$(2-x)x=(2-y)y=(2-z)z = \sqrt{3\lambda}\to \text { WLOG } x = y, x+z = 2$ is the worse case since the ideal case is $x = y = z = 1$. Thus $f(x,y,z) = f(x)=\dfrac{2}{2-x}+\dfrac{1}{x}$. From this you can use derivative to finish and find the minimum value of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much Ganymede. I'll try it from your hints.

Comment: I am sure that the minimum value of P less than 3. I am calculating since your hints.

Comment: I define the Lagrange to be $L(x, y, z, t)=\dfrac{1}{2-x}+\dfrac{1}{2-y}+\dfrac{1}{2-z}-t(x^3+y^3+z^3-3)$. The critical points are solutions to $L_x=0,L_y=0,L_z=0, L_t=0$, then $(2-x)x=(2-y)y=(2-z)z = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3t}}=\sqrt{3 \lambda}$. I found $x=2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. Is it right?

Comment: Its true. That's what I got also.

Comment: Thank you! But why do you have WLOG $x=z, x+z=2$?

Comment: All cases lead to those 2 cases.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: Do you understand I mean? Why $x=y,x+z=2$? Can you clarify it?

Comment: Since your hints I can find $\min P= \dfrac{3+2\sqrt{2}}{2} \iff x=y=2(\sqrt{2}-1),z=4-2\sqrt{2}$. But I think that you're wrong.

Comment: I put $x=y=0.001; z=\sqrt[3]{3-2 \times (0.001)^3}$ then we have $$P< \dfrac{3+2\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ So, your ANS is wrong.

Comment: Anyway, your ANS is not correct! :( Can you fix it?????

Comment: When I put $x,y,z$ as above, then I have $P \approx 2.79 <\dfrac{3+2\sqrt{2}}{2} \approx 2.9$. :)

Comment: I think that $P(x \to 0^+,y \to 0^+,z \to \sqrt[3]{3}^-)=\inf_{x^3+y^3+z^3=3}{P}$. It's not minimum value of $P$.

Comment: ^_^ Can you find $\min P$?

Comment: "I am working on it now." o_0 I'm waiting...your ANS.

Comment: Have you got a solution? o_0...............I'm waiting here! :)

Comment: You say a lie. :(

Comment: You should accept what you wrote because it's your thoughts about my problem. It also proves you are the adult, not a boy. No one can know everything, even the professors still learn, nothing to be ashamed if you do not know the ANS. So you do not have to delete the comments when you wrote it out here. Thanks! :)

Comment: I think its fair when I asked you a question, you should answer and you asked me a question, I answer.